# Two Submit Buttons on Single Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is it possible to have two submit buttons on a single form, one of which launches the submit but also passes a parameter to the URL? Perhaps using js/jquery to intercept the action and append the param somehow. i.e.,

```
<form action="/doStuff" method="post">
    <input id="name" type="text"></input>
    <button id="save" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button id="save-with-param" type="submit">Save as Draft</button>
</form>
```

Clicking save would send:

```
localhost:8080/myApp/doStuff
```

and clicking `save-with-param` would send:

```
localhost:8080/myApp/doStuff?param=XYZ
```

Comment: use `onclick` event handlers to `submit` separately

Comment: @vinayakj a `form` can be submitted by other ways than clicking submit button, e.g pressing enter when button is focused

Comment: @A.Wolff for that OP can capture `keyCode==13` also OP mentions _Clicking save would return_.

Comment: @vinayakj This is typically something to do without JavaScript. There is no need.

Comment: Why do you want to change the url? The value of the button is posted along with the other form data. Can't you check the post data?

Comment: I know. Hence my question: *must* it be in the url, or would checking the post parameter be an alternative? You *can* post the button value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On all moder browsers, you can use `formaction` attribute:

```
<form action="/doStuff" method="post">
    <input id="name" type="text"></input>
    <button id="save" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button id="save-with-param" type="submit" formaction="/doStuff?param=XYZ">Save as Draft</button>
</form>
```

To support older browsers, e.g IE9<, you could add support using:

```
;(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        if (typeof document.createElement('input').formAction === "undefined") {
            $(':submit[formaction]').closest('form').data('defaultFormAction', this.action).on('submit', function () {
                var $focused = $(':focus');
                $(this).attr('action', $focused.is('[formaction]') ? $focused.attr('formAction') : $(this).data('defaultFormAction'));
            });
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Nice solution. Notice browser support though, especially if you need to support IE9-.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save-with-param").on("click", function() {
        var action = $('form').attr('action') + "?param=XYZ";
        $('form').attr('action', action);
    });
});
```